# Logstash Plug-in Development

Tags: logstash

I am trying to develop a new logstash plugin in my development Elasticsearch stack environment.

I started with generating the skeleton for my new plug-in using the logstash-plugin generate utility. Once I had this in place I then was able to build my plug-in using the gem build utility which ran without error and created a gem for me. I then ran the logstash-plugin install utility which successfully installed my plug-in.

The entry in my logstash.gem looks like this--
`gem "logstash-output-s3-4.3.3", "0.1.0", :path => "./vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-s3-4.3.3"`

I then took the code from the actual logstash plug-in that I'm hoping to modify and copied it into my new plug-in directory and then created a new logstash.conf file to test with using my new plug-in and started the logstash service. It ran as expected moving data from the servers that were being watched in the appropriate s3 buckets.

logstash.conf output section--

```
output {
s3{
    region => "us-east-1"
    bucket => "xxxx"
    prefix => "Dev/xxxx/%{+YYYY}/%{+MM}/%{+dd}/"
    server_side_encryption => true
    server_side_encryption_algorithm => "aws:kms"
    ssekms_key_id => "xxxx"
    validate_credentials_on_root_bucket => false
    codec => "json_lines"
    size_file => 1024000
    time_file => 5
    rotation_strategy => "size_and_time"
    temporary_directory => "../../LogstashS3OutputData/temp/"
    canned_acl => "private"
}

s3{
    region => "us-east-1"
    bucket => "xxxx"
    prefix => "Dev/xxxx/%{+YYYY}/%{+MM}/%{+dd}/"
    server_side_encryption => true
    server_side_encryption_algorithm => "aws:kms"
    ssekms_key_id => "xxxx"
    validate_credentials_on_root_bucket => false
    codec => "json_lines"
    size_file => 1024000
    time_file => 5
    rotation_strategy => "size_and_time"
    temporary_directory => "../../LogstashS3OutputData/temp/"
    canned_acl => "private"
}
}
```

My next step was and this is where I am having issues was to try and create a new property for the plug-in called file_prefix--

```
s3{
    region => "us-east-1"
    bucket => "xxxx"
    prefix => "Dev/xxxx/xxxx/%{+YYYY}/%{+MM}/%{+dd}/"
    file_prefix => "test"
    server_side_encryption => true
    server_side_encryption_algorithm => "aws:kms"
    ssekms_key_id => "arn:aws:kms:xxxx"
    validate_credentials_on_root_bucket => false
    codec => "json_lines"
    size_file => 1024000
    time_file => 5
    rotation_strategy => "size_and_time"
    temporary_directory => "../../LogstashS3OutputData/temp/"
    canned_acl => "private"
}
```

I modified the following files in my solution
\vendor\bundle\jruby\2.5.0\gems\logstash-output-s3-4.3.3\spec\outputs\s3_spec.rb

added "file_prefix" => file_prefix at line 15
\vendor\bundle\jruby\2.5.0\gems\logstash-output-s3-4.3.3\spec\supports\helpers.rb

added let(:file_prefix) {} at line line 12
added "file_prefix" => file_prefix, at line 19
\vendor\bundle\jruby\2.5.0\gems\logstash-output-s3-4.3.3\lib\logstash\outputs\s3.rb

added config :file_prefix, :validate => :string right after the statement config :prefix, :validate => :string, :default => '' at line 154
added @file_prefix = file_prefix at line 226
Now when I start the logstash service I get this error message
Unknown setting 'file_prefix' for s3

I've searched and I've tried everything I can think but I can't get past this hurdle.

TIA,
Bill Youngman

Answer (score 0):

This can be considered closed as I am using a similar feature request in the s3 output plugin developer branch as a starting point for my project.

Thanks,
-Bill